# How to show traffic and estimate time on the map route like google map?

Tags: android

I work on a project and I want to show road traffic and time estimates on the map route, like the `Googlemap`.
.[![Like this image
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8H30W.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8H30W.png)

```
if (direction.isOK()) {
                Route route = direction.getRouteList().get(0);
                ArrayList<LatLng> directionPositionList = route.getLegList().get(0).getDirectionPoint();
                polyline = mGoogleMap.addPolyline(DirectionConverter.createPolyline(mActivity, directionPositionList, 5
                        , Color.BLUE));
                setCameraWithCoordinationBounds(route);

                    Leg leg = route.getLegList().get(0);
                    Info distanceInfo = leg.getDistance();
                    Info durationInfo = leg.getDuration();
                    String distance = distanceInfo.getText();
                    String duration = durationInfo.getText();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using google maps sdk, you can enable traffic details once app has your location.

```
           @Override
           public void onMyLocationChange(Location arg0) {
             mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(arg0.getLatitude(), arg0.getLongitude())).title("Here"));

             //load the traffic now
              googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
           }
          });
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also try the following code. It initializes the map properly then sets traffic data after detecting your current location.

```
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {


             mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {

           @Override
           public void onMyLocationChange(Location arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(arg0.getLatitude(), arg0.getLongitude())).title("It's Me!"));

             //load the traffic now
              googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
           }
          });

            }
        }
    }
```